# Написать рекурсивную функцию в lisp, попарное сложение элементов подсписков

Tags: алгоритм, рекурсия, lisp, common-lisp

Начинаю разбираться в лиспе, но застыл на одной задаче
Собственно вот задание,

> Написать функцию, на вход которой подается **список из двух списков**
> чисел. Результатом работы функции должен стать список, элементами
> которого являются поэлементные суммы этих двух подсписков. Например:
> ((1 3 2)(4 6 3)) ==> (5 9 5)

Нужно сделать без использования циклов, функционалов и без функции присвоения
Застыл на том что не могу понять как написать что бы он **одновременно просматривал два подмассива** и сочетал элементы попарно.

Напишите, пожалуйста.

С меня как обычно ничего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм прост:

1. Если один из списков пустой - вернуть второй список
2. В противном случае

   1. Взять головы списков и сложить
   2. вызвать рекурсивно функцию с хвостами списков
   3. вернуть новый список, в котором в качестве головы будет сумма, а в качестве хвоста - результат рекурсивного вызова.

Например:

```
(defun  zip (a b)
    (cond
        ((NULL a) b)
        ((NULL b) a)
        (T (cons (+ (car a) (car b)) (zip (cdr a) (cdr b))))
    )
)
```

Comment: Надо же, я тоже еще чего-то помню. Но в emacs (другого лиспа у меня нет), чтобы заработало, пришлось написать `(defun NULL (a)   (if (eq a ()) t nil))`, заменить  в `(cond ...)` `T` на `t` и вызывать получилось только так -- `(zip \`(1 3 2) \`(4 6 3))`

Comment: @avp, с вызовом все ок, перед списком надо `quote` ставить, чтобы он не считался вызовом функции. По поводу NULL - в разных диалектах по разному проверка на пустой список делается, от этого уж никуда не уйти

Comment: Так, то ты прав, но суть в том что на вход подаётся один список с двумя подсписками, в этом для меня трудность и состоит, как обходить список тогда?

Comment: @StillStealSteel, подсписков всегда два?

Comment: Допустим что да

Comment: По сути на вход функции должен поступать один список.

Comment: @StillStealSteel, напишите обертку, которая вызовет `zip` с двумя первыми элементами списка. Наверное так -- `(defun z2 (a) (zip (car a) (cadr a)))`

Comment: @avp Как-то костыльно получается да и не работает почему-то всё равно, хотелось бы увидеть как это на самом деле должно было выглядеть, по сути, что бы разобрать алгоритм.

Comment: @StillStealSteel, все сведется именно к такому подходу, просто вместо именованной функции может быть лямбда

Comment: @Grundy что вы имеете ввиду? можно на коде посмотреть о чем вы говорите, хочу увидеть что бы лучше разобраться что к чему, пожалуйста

Comment: @StillStealSteel, я имею ввиду, что конечный вид будет примерно таким `(defun z2 (a) (zip (car a) (cadr a)))` в любом случае. Если заранее известно, что во входном списке два элемента.

Comment: @Grundy My bad, скобку не дописал _лисп всё же ведь_ , теперь работает, спасибо за помощь)